# R: reshaping a dataframe and creating proportions

Tags: r, reshape

I am new to programming and would appreciate any help with this.
I have a data frame that contains products names and the day when it was sold. For each product, I'd need to see the fraction that are sold in on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.

Please follow this to replicate my dataframe:

```
Product=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
Day=c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Saturday","Sunday" ,"Monday")
df=data.frame(cbind(Product,Day))
```

I tried the following:

```
data.frame(prop.table(with(df,table(Product,Day))))

df.wide=reshape(data.frame(prop.table(with(df,table(Product,Day)))),
                  timevar="Day",
                  idvar="Product",
                  direction="wide")
```

which gives me

```
Product Freq.Friday Freq.Monday Freq.Saturday Freq.Sunday Freq.Thursday Freq.Tuesday Freq.Wednesday
       A   0.1111111  0.11111111    0.11111111  0.00000000     0.1111111   0.11111111     0.11111111
       B   0.0000000  0.05555556    0.00000000  0.00000000     0.0000000   0.05555556     0.05555556
       C   0.0000000  0.05555556    0.05555556  0.05555556     0.0000000   0.00000000     0.00000000
```

I can sum columns 2-8 and get total proportion of A,B,C sold but how do I obtain proportion of A,B,C sold by Day of the week?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward `table` operation when combined with `prop.table(...,margin=)`. the `margin=` argument allows for calculating proportions for rows, columns or the whole table (default) `prop.table(...,1)` does rows; `2` does columns, `3` does strata etc..

Also, instead of `data.frame`, use `as.data.frame.matrix` to avoid the reshape requirement:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(prop.table(with(df,table(Product,Day)),1))
#     Friday    Monday  Saturday    Sunday  Thursday   Tuesday Wednesday
#A 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
#B 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333
#C 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000

as.data.frame.matrix(prop.table(with(df,table(Product,Day)),2))
#  Friday Monday  Saturday Sunday Thursday   Tuesday Wednesday
#A      1   0.50 0.6666667      0        1 0.6666667 0.6666667
#B      0   0.25 0.0000000      0        0 0.3333333 0.3333333
#C      0   0.25 0.3333333      1        0 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

You might also want to consider making `day` a `factor` with the `levels` in an appropriate Sunday-Saturday order.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I actually want to obtain proportion sold in each day per product. For example if A accounts for 0.25 of the sales, I also need what porportion of A is sold on each day, making the sum of A=1. For example if 0.2 of A were sold on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday, and 0 on Saturday and Sunday, my total for A would be 1. I am sorry if this wasn't very clear above

Comment: @RUser - both % within product and % within day options are above already!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

ddply(dcast(df, Product ~ Day),1,function(u) data.frame(u[1], u[-1]/sum(u[-1])))

#  Product    Friday    Monday  Saturday    Sunday  Thursday   Tuesday Wednesday
#1       A 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
#2       B 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333
#3       C 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: you can post it as an answer, it is another point of view solving the problem!

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I actually want to obtain proportion sold in each day per product. For example if A accounts for 0.25 of the sales, I also need what porportion of A is sold on each day, making the sum of A=1. For example if 0.2 of A were sold on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday, and 0 on Saturday and Sunday, my total for A would be 1. I am sorry if this wasn't very clear above.